# Adding secondary axis and making grid lines equal

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to add a secondary axis to a plot and make the grid lines equally spaced along y, but I the code below doesn't do what it is supposed to. y2A,y2B values are not right - they refer to xlim values not ylim. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def CtoF(y):
    return y * 1.8 + 32
def FtoC(y):
    return (y - 32) / 1.8

def setAxis2(ax1):
    ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(CtoF, FtoC))
    ax2.set_ylabel('Fahrenheit')
    return ax2

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

plt.plot(x,y)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.set_ylabel('Celsius')

ax1.grid()

#Add the 2nd axis for Fahrenheit
ax2 = setAxis2(ax1)

#Get the ylimits and space them equally
[y1A,y1B] = ax1.get_ylim()
[y2A,y2B] = ax2.get_ylim()
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(y1A,y1B, 10))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(y2A,y2B, 10)) #Doesn't work

print(y1A,y1B) #
print(y2A,y2B) #Doesn't output the expected values
```

I tried another method that works well (with the same versions of matplotlib), but the question remains about the issue above. The method that works is below:

```
ticks1 = ax1.get_yticks()
ticks2 = CtoF(ticks1)
ax2.set_yticks(ticks2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting `y2A` and `y2B` from the y-limits of `ax2`, we can calculate them directly with `CtoF`:

```
# Get the y-limits and space them equally.
y1A, y1B = ax1.get_ylim()
y2A, y2B = map(CtoF, (y1A, y1B))
n = 10
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(y1A, y1B, n))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(y2A, y2B, n))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - yes, I found a work around, but curious as to why [y2A,y2B]  in my code is 0,1